# which programming language I should use between java and ruby for creating Android and iPhone app

Tags: java, android, iphone, ruby, smartphone

I am considering to create a web browser which is different from 
normal one, which focuses on English learner or helps you to understand difficult English for instance, thesis, legal document etc.
so I will add like a dictionary, new service(I wanna make it secret) etc
and I wanna create web page or application too, but 
the web app's contents are different from the browser's one completely,
if users put a PDF file, it returns a new pdf file that is re-written somewhat(I wanna make this secret).

in a nutshell, I wanna create Android app, iPhone app and web app.

my basic info:
I am good at java. and now I'm studying ruby.

I know creating an Android app, I'd better use java.
However, for creating an iPhone app, I cannot use java,
and I don't want to use Objective-c either.
for creating web app, I will use ruby.

what programming language you recommend?
thank you for reading this question and answering !
PS.
My mother tongue is NOT English, so sorry if I make mistakes.

Comment: Have you considered using something like http://phonegap.com/ ?

Comment: Probably... JavaScript.

Comment: In the first line, you say you are considering a web browser. Then you say "the" web app is different from "the" browser. Then in the second paragraph, you say you "wanna" create a web app. I have no idea how all this can make sense.

Comment: This is an extremely large scoped project.  I would suggest first making a simple use-case and then creating a proof-of-concept for that to get an idea of the amount of work necessary for the rest.  Regarding the choice of software, for the prototype use the native tools for the given platform simply to learn what you need to look for when choosing the toolchain for the full project.

Comment: @sawa I meant the contents are different.
offcurse, web app and web browser themselves are different.
sorry to make you confuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua programming language is awesome for creating Android and iPhone Apps, You can Check this 
[Corona SDK](http://www.coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/), Corona SDK is awesome and simple to use for creating Android and iPhone Apps, And for web apps Ruby is awesome for web Apps and You can See PHP too.

I hope that I helped you. 
:)

Comment: Do you have experience with using Corona in production software, i.e. apps delivered to customers?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes I created an Android game from 1 year ago it get about 7,500 downloads but I deleted it from the Play Store.

Comment: @Kevin Martin thank you Kevin.
I didn't know Lua.
what language is similar to Lua ?

Comment: I wanna know if MobiRuby is good for creating iPhone app too

Comment: @SamuraiT This was the search result for developing iPhone apps using Ruby
http://www.rubymotion.com/

Comment: @KevinMartin RubyMotion is awesome !
that looks so easy to develop iPhone apps !
I will use RubyMotion to develop an iPhone app!!
thak you